# Complex equations in AC RLC circuits spiralling out of control

Tags: ac, inductor, passive-networks, homework, conductors

I'm trying to solve the following circuit. I tried using superposition to find Thevenin at V_o.

First I solved for V_o with the current source and dependant source, then I solved for V_o with the voltage source and the dependant source.

I transform from time domain to phasor domain every time, and I was planning on converting back to time domain to add the V_o's I got with superposition at the end.

The problem is my equation spirals out of control really fast, with incredibly large and small values. I tried solving it without simplifying but every time I lose myself in the equations.

Is there any way to simplify the working with complex numbers part?

[image: Question]

Here is what (I tried) doing for the superposed circuit with the current source

[image: computations]

Comment: Source I is an AC signal with twice the frequency. Source V is an AC signal with a phase delay of -pi/2. Consider using variables of the impedances such as Cs1, Ls1 and Cs2, Ls2 (where s1 = 2s2. which will be helpful later). First dealing with superposition:
Find Vo1 = f(I,L,C,R,s1) = TF(Transfer function) * I = find the numerical value
Find Vo2 = f(V,L,C,R,s2) = TF(Transfer function) * V = find the numerical value
Vo = Vo1 + Vo2, this is where s1=2*s2 will come in handy. Careful with the transfer functions, they add phase difference and amplification for particular frequencies.